# DateTime is resettings back to 01/01/0001 on Azure Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, datetime

I am using ASP.NET EF and am trying to get a DateTime out of my model into my controller. My model is in the format 'dd/mm/yyyy' and when I bring it into the controller, I want to add 10 hours to it and send it to another controller to use this date. This code works locally but I am hosting on Azure so it needs to convert it to UTC timezone from NZ timezone.

I am getting the error:

> ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The added or subtracted value results in an un-representable DateTime.

I believe this is because the value is setting itself back to 01/01/0001 but I can run locally and it works perfectly.

View Code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.SiteID)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Date, DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"), new { 
    @class = "form-control" })
    <button type="submit" name="type" value="invoice" class="btn btn-primary" 
    onclick="document.body.style.cursor='wait'">Generate Invoices</button>
}
```

Controller Code (viewModel passes in the date):

```
public ActionResult Run(RunViewModel viewModel, string type)
    {
        var logger = new MemoryLogger();

        if (type == "invoice")
        {
            var date = viewModel.Date.AddHours(10);
            var xeroCommandParameters = new XeroCommandParameters
            {
                Logger = logger,
                LocalDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(date, NewZealand),
            };
```

Comment: Why are you not using ISO8601 format for your date/datetime ? A value formatted as `dd/MM/yyyy` is ambiguous as it can be evaluated in different ways depending on the culture of the machine.

Comment: So looking at that format, are you suggesting using something like yyyy-mm-dd. I would just prefer it to be displayed in the view of format: dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: The display is a presentation layer issue. You need to make sure that when the data is actually submitted to the server that the formatted value conforms to ISO8601 notation, regardless of how it is actually rendered/displayed in the browser.

Comment: Make sure both side time culture must be same.